# Left multiplication operator in Banach Algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-algebras

Suppose $A$ is a Banach algebra and $x \in A$. Consider the left multiplication operator $M_x$:
$$
M_x(y) = xy.
$$
Assume that $M_x$ is invertible. Does that imply that $x$ is invertible in $A$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$M_x$ is invertible implies $M_x$ is surjective implies, there exists $y$ such that $M_x(y)=xy=1$. Thus $x$ has a right inverse.

$M_y$ is an open map since $M_x$ is invertible (Let $U$ be an open subset, $M_x(M_y(U))=U$ is open thus $M_y(U)$ is open). Since $M_y(0)=0$, for every $z$, there exists a constant $c: cz\in M_y(U_0)$ where $U_0$ is a neighborhood of $0$ since $M_y$ is open, thus $M_y$ is surjective, $M_y$ is injective $(yz=0$ implies $x(yz)=z=0)$ thus $M_y$ is open and bijective thus $M_y$ is invertible, there exist $z$ such that $M_y(z)=yz=1, x(yz)=x=(xy)z=z$ thus $x=z$ and $xy=yx=1$ thus $x$ is invertible.

Comment: Thanks! But can you explain the thing with $M_y$ being open? In particular, I did not get this: "$M_x(M_y(U))=U$ is open thus $M_y(U)$ is open".

Comment: And why does $xz \in U$ implies $y(xz) = z$?

Comment: $M_x(M_y(U))=U$ i.e $M_y(U)={M_x}^{-1}(U)$ since $M_x$ is an homeomorphism, basic set theory, and $U$ open implies ${M_x}^{-1}(U)$ is open since $M_x$ is continue.

Comment: Couldn't you just say $M_xM_y = I$ so multiplying by $M_x^{-1}$ from the left we get $M_y = M_x^{-1}$. Therefore $M_xM_y = M_yM_x= I$ so plugging in $1$ we get $xy = yx = 1$, i.e. $y = x^{-1}$.